# How could a user with a single point cast votes?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, privileges

[image]

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/653457/nour-g?tab=profile) user has not been more than at least $15$ reputation. Why can they cast votes?

Comment: The user got the "Student" and "Scholar" badges on 12 Mar ( First question with score of 1 or more; Ask a question and accept an answer) + he accepted an answer on 13 Mar which assuming he got two up voted on the first question (which is probably deleted now) gives him $5+5+2+2$ which is enough for an up vote which he cast on the same day Mar 13 since he got the "Supporter" badge (First up vote).

Comment: @kingW3 I had not thought of the badges. That's a nice idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The user had sufficiently many points in the past, due to a post that is now deleted. Absent evidence to the contrary, I assume they had cast the votes while they had enough points to do so.

Comment: Also the daily tracker only puts what's left at the end of the day. So just because a user doesn't show to have had those points, doesn't mean a thing. just from my recent graph you would hardly know I got to 1800+ before giving out 3 bounties worth 500 each it's nearly off my graph.